# Flex single swf worker - with no lifecycle events or constructor, how is the worker configured?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I don't see lifecycle events being triggered for a worker in Flex using the same swf. I need to keep the amount of swf data small, so I'd like to use the same swf for both threads since they use similar code. Without lifecycle events, I am unable to initialize the worker thread. I can share data with the worker, but without initialization, it's really not useful. I'd like to avoid creating a separate class for the Worker. Is there any event that is *within* the worker that could be used to initialize?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" applicationDPI="160"  preinitialize="preInitializeHandler(event)"
               initialize="initializeHandler()"
               creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler()"
               applicationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function init():void 
            { trace("Application Complete");
                var swfBytes:ByteArray = this.loaderInfo.bytes; 
                if (Worker.current.isPrimordial) {
                    var bgWorker:Worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(swfBytes); 
                    bgWorker.addEventListener(Event.WORKER_STATE, workerHandler);
                    bgWorker.start();
                }
            }

            private function preInitializeHandler(event:Event):void{
                var p:Event=event;
                trace("Pre Initialize");
            }

            private function initializeHandler():void{
                trace("Initialize");
            }

            private function creationCompleteHandler():void{
                trace("Creation Complete");
            }

            private function workerHandler(event:Event):void{
                trace("Worker is running");
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Output:

```
[SWF] FlexMobileWorkerTest.swf - 3,697,251 bytes after decompression
Pre Initialize
Initialize
Creation Complete
Application Complete
Worker is running
[SWF] FlexMobileWorkerTest.swf - 3,697,251 bytes after decompression
```

Comment: initialize what? Your worker is already running so start using it.

Comment: You need to think about your term 'using it'. It's a single swf, not a separate class. In AIR, the single swf works because the class constructor can have statements added, ie 'using it'. The worker created above can only receive messages, which communicates data, not object construction. It may be that I'm thinking about single swf workers in flex incorrectly, but I'm not sure how else to do it.

Comment: Obviously I can tell the worker is running, otherwise I wouldn't have printed "Worker is running" to show the event. The point is with the single swf above, even if there was code to setup a worker thread, it wouldn't be called in Flex, but is called in AIR applications due to the constructor. I've changed the original question to reflect this explanation.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid creating a separate Worker class?  That's going to be a lot easier than trying to set up a system in an `Application` subclass.

Comment: Yes, good question. I also realize using the single swf is generally frowned upon, and appears to be a dumb decision. There are a few reasons, minimize swf size (although it is tiny), reduce complexity - for multiple applications I can just load one class for all the threads. The implementing user doesn't have to rebuild the worker class separately, as far as I can tell FB doesn't support auto building for workers in libraries.

Comment: Lastly, there are some compliance regulations we're going to be bumping up against in some apps that mandate a re-characterization by sets of byte code. If the two byte code are the same, I can declare them tested, and there would only be one set of red tape documents. If I have to go with a separate worker I can, but it seems like an oversight in Flex. A simple event saying I'm Alive would solve the issue.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't frown on a single SWF.  Lots of Worker examples use a single-SWF architecture.  However, they all depend on having an `isPrimordial` check in the constructor, and MXML doesn't let you define a constructor.

Comment: Exactly. Seems like it's a bug, like there should be an event to compensate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in this configuration.

A typical example of configuring a single-SWF Worker is:

```
public class MadWorker extends Sprite
{
    private var workerName:String = "AverageWorker";

    public function MadWorker()
    {
        super();
        init();
    }

    private function init()
    {
        var swfBytes:ByteArray = this.loaderInfo.bytes; 
        if (Worker.current.isPrimordial) {
            this.workerName = "PrimordialWorker";
            trace("Primordial worker setup");

            var bgWorker:Worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(swfBytes);
            bgWorker.addEventListener(Event.WORKER_STATE, workerHandler);
            bgWorker.start();
        } else {
            trace("Non-primordial worker setup");
            //Start long-running calculation
        }
    }

    private function workerHandler(event:Event):void{
        trace("Worker is running: " + this.workerName);
    }
}
```

The fact that `init()` is called in the constructor is very important; when a Worker is created, it simply calls the constructor of the class.  This is no problem when you define your class in Actionscript, but it's a showstopper in MXML (you can't define a constructor for an MXML component - see the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf688f1-7ff1.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a3a) and [How to make MXML Component Constructor with Arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863209/how-to-make-mxml-component-constructor-with-arguments) for more on this).

Unfortunately, you can't just extend `Application` for your main class; you'll just get "Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor." [This Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-20420) has details.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, I'll give it another week.

Comment: Giving this credit as the correct answer, it's not possible in Flex.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you think a worker is just another instance of your class and should fire the same events? A worker has no stage, no display list, it is literally just a thread and it will never generate or receive any other events than just the ones Workers are meant to dispatch and receive.

Once a worker is created you can then create the necessary message channels and properties to ensure a two way communication. Workers won't do anything else, I'm not sure what or why you are expecting them to do more than just that?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is another instance of the same class - it's using the exact same byte code as the original. However, I do not expect the events to fire, because the original application is already rendered.

Comment: Are you saying that using a single thread swf in Flex is not possible, but possible in AIR due to the constructor? If there was an Application constructor to override in Flex, I could create statements in the worker that create objects. In the code above, the worker will never create objects because init() is never called, so having communication is useless.

Comment: Or, if there was an event in Flex that said "Class Initialized" I could trigger off that, but as it stands, there is no way to build objects in the Worker to recognize messages and act on them.

Comment: Certainly doing it using mxml is trickier since that code is not used as is but compiled later into classes and then compiled into the final swf but this is till possible by extracting a given target class from the bytearray. I'll show an example later on when I have more time.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering - I do realize on the surface, this appears to be a really dumb question, but is a subtle use issue. I've posted this a few times, and either got no responses or down voted. Yes - I'm assuming that class extraction is at run time, so I could use the same loaderInfo data.